# Sublime Text 2 - Package Control installed but the list not shown

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, package-control

I am using Sublime Text 2 for Mac. I have installed the Package Control for Sublime Text 2, following the instructions from https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2 without any trouble. However, when I open up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shif</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to search for available packages, it does not show any.

See the image screenshot here

[image]

Do you have any solutions for it? I try restart Sublime but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It appears that it didn't install *without any trouble*. On osx, it's command + shift + p. You haven't provided enough information to allow anyone to help you.

Comment: Also check the ST console for errors when you restart ST. If there are any, please include those in your question.

Comment: It look like I did not properly restart the Sublime Text. When I turn off my Mac and open it again, the Package Control list showed up. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Take a look in your user `Preferences.sublime-settings` and remove the Package Control from the `"ignored_packages"` list if it is there.

If you use a Linux based system, you may have to check permissions of `/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3`. Check if the directory is owned by your user. If not, change the owner user for that directory.

On Mac OS, Sublime Text (menu) -> Settings.
[image: How to access sublime settings on MAC OS]

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug. It usually happens when I restore my Sublime Text's preferences backup copying the files to ST's User folder.

Comment: I have no idea how it got into my `ignored_packages`, but it was there! (I'm using Sublime Text 3)

Comment: What the *#$? How did that get into my user settings? Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @alfakini Can you mention in your answer how to find "Preferences.sublime-settings"?

Comment: "Preferences.sublime-settings" is in Packages/User/. Open the file up and delete the line that says "Package Control"

Comment: you can go to "Preferences.sublime-settings" by clicking "Preferences" tab then "Settings".

Comment: @alfakini please add in answer.
if you use Linux based system you may have to check permission table of your /home/[USER]/.config/sublime-text-3
check it all directory is own by your current USER. if not change USER for that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Click the `Preferences > Browse Packages` and check whether Package control file is there or not.

You can manually put package control file there by downloading it from [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) and get rid of issues.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I had to restart my computer to properly reset Sublime Text 2. It seems from your comment that you also got the Package Control list to show up after restarting your computer.

Your screenshot image is currently broken, but make sure you have the zipfile "Package Control.sublime-package" in the Installed Packages directory.

Comment: After trying all the solutions above I reluctantly restarted since I have multiple tabs/apps open. But it worked!

Comment: Thank you Moue :)

Answer (score 2):

If @alfakini's answer (accepted answer) does not work for you.
The issue could be related to openssl 3 causing import issues in newer versions of Mac OS (Big Sur and above) based on https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1612.

Running the below line in my terminal fixes the issue for me:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1o/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Hope this helps others as well.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked for me after running command and restarting sublime text. I'm on Mac OS X Ventura 13.6 / Sublime Text 3

Comment: This solved my problem too, with MacOS Ventura 13.4.1 and Sublime Text 4.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

#### Open the console and run this command:

`curl http://sublime.wbond.net/Package%20Control.sublime-package -o ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Installed\ Packages/Package\ Control.sublime-package`

Then restart sublime.

See this issue: https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/652

Comment: surprisingly I am getting an error: curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Comment: There's a missing \ to escape space between Text and 2

Comment: "Syntax Error: invalid syntax". There is a working console command here: https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2