# Sublime Text 2 Package Control installed but is deleted upon Restart

Tags: sublimetext2, package-managers, package-control

I have copied `Package Control.sublime-package` in the directory `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Installed\ Packages/`
as per instructions in 
https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2

However, after restarting Sublime, the file gets deleted!

None of the answers in [Sublime Text 2 - Package Control installed but the list not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450091/sublime-text-2-package-control-installed-but-the-list-not-shown) helps to solve this problem.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried doing the installation via the Console as detailed on the [Installation for ST2](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2) page?

Comment: I did and it threw errors, but now I did again and it worked :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tried to install using the console, and manually as instructed from that site, and no matter which way I attempt to install it, the Package Control.sublime-package file gets deleted from "Installed Packages/" directory upon restarting Sublime Text 2.