# Cannot install Package Control in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, package-managers

I have followed the instructions at this location:
https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2

It doesn't matter if I copy and paste the code into the console, or manually place the download file into the `Installed Packages/` directory, upon restarting Sublime Text 2, the file is deleted from the directory.

The exact same question is asked here, [Sublime Text 2 Package Control installed but is deleted upon Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844131/sublime-text-2-package-control-installed-but-is-deleted-upon-restart)

but there is not a solution for that question.

Sublime Text 2 version 2.0.2, Build 2221

Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: Same there:

Sublime Text 2 version 2.0.2, Build 2221
Mac OS 10.6.8